# Get a correct path from random data

Tags: python, django, database, loops, for-loop

On my index page, I have an image gallery. When someone clicks on an image,  it should show more information with more photos in another page. All are loading from MySQL database using a `for` loop. I'm unable to get the detail of clicked image from my data base. It loads all the data

This page's process is like a news website -- all the news loading from a loop. if someone clicks on a news item it should only show details about the clicked item.

Below is my `index.html` page, my `urls.py` and `views.py` source code also.

I'm using Python, Django with MySQL; all latest versions.

[Home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZaDl.jpg), [source code of my images gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTx0d.jpg)

```
{% for x in destination %}
<!-- Destination -->
<a href="destination" id="{{x.id}}"><div class="destination item" >
    <div class="destination_image">
        <img src="{{x.img.url}}" alt="">
        {% if x.offer %}
        <div class="spec_offer text-center"><a >Special Offer</a></div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="destination_content">
        <div class="destination_title"><a href="">{{x.name}}</a></div>
        <div class="destination_subtitle"><p>{{x.short_description}}</p></div>
        <div class="destination_price">From ${{x.price}}</div>
    </div>
</div></a>

{% endfor %}
```

```python
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('destination', views.destination, name='destination'),
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

```python
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Destination


def destination(request):
    dest = Destination
    return render(request, 'destination.html', {'sub_destination': dest})
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the href attribute of `<a>` tag, try to insert the parameter of the image into href to open in new page (maybe the primary key of image).

On the new page, just retrieve the information of the picture and show it to the client.

Comment: thank you. i am sorry i couldn't write before one thing important....I'm usin python, Django with MySQL. all a letest versions. how everthank you so much for answering me kindly

Comment: The OP is using Django, why should they waste time on PHP here?

Comment: thank you but it is the sameresults. loading all the images what are there in the object..still I'm unable to get it